# Как реализовать поиск в asp.net mvc который будет учитывать регистр?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть проект магазина в asp.net mvc, в нем есть поиск по книгам, но проблема в том, что поиск не учитывает регистр. Как быть?

код в представлении:

```
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("_BookSearch", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "results" }))
        {
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Наименование книги" aria-label="Наименование книги" aria-describedby="button-addon2" name="name">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="button-addon2" value="Поиск">Поиск</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        <div id="results"></div>
```

код в контроллере:

```
        public ActionResult _BookSearch(string name)
    {
        var allbooks = db.Books.Where(a => a.Name.Contains(name)).ToList();
        if (allbooks.Count <= 0)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return PartialView(allbooks);
    }
```

Comment: `исходный текст.ToLower() == искомый текст.ToLower()`. Ну или как там у вас поиск идет, может так: `коллекция.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ToLower() == искомый текст.ToLower())`. Суть думаю понятна...

Comment: Вы используете EF или что?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ топикастаеру нужно наоборот :)

Comment: Покажите, как у вас сейчас реализован поиск. Можете добавить в вопрос свой код?

Comment: @Dmitry пример от EvgeniyZ - это как *не учитывать* регистр, а вы вроде бы наоборот, хотите его учитывать? :)

Comment: Это зависит от используемой РСУБД. Думаю, у вас Sql Server. По умолчанию там case insensitive. Посмотрите ответы в этой теме: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3843060/5045688. Суть: нужно изменить collation в БД.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле все оказалось куда проще, чем я думал

```
public ActionResult _BookSearch(string name)
    {
        var allbooks = db.Books.Where(a => a.Name.Contains(name)).ToList();
        if (allbooks.Count <= 0)
        {
            allbooks = db.Books.Where(a => a.Name.ToLower().Contains(name)).ToList();
            if (allbooks.Count <= 0)
            {
                allbooks = db.Books.Where(a => a.Name.ToUpper().Contains(name)).ToList();
            };
            if (allbooks.Count <= 0)
            {
                allbooks = db.Books.Where(a => a.Author.Contains(name)).ToList();
            };
            if (allbooks.Count <= 0)
            {
                allbooks = db.Books.Where(a => a.Author.ToLower().Contains(name)).ToList();
            };
            if (allbooks.Count <= 0)
            {
                allbooks = db.Books.Where(a => a.Author.ToUpper().Contains(name)).ToList();
            };
        };
        return PartialView(allbooks);
    }
```